# Abelian groups and Sylow-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a finite group $G$, if the number of all Sylow p-Subgroups is one, then, $G$ is abelian, right? My question is, whether the other direction is also true.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, all its subgroups are normal. Hence there is a unique $p$-Sylow for each prime $p$.

Comment: In the first direction, it is false: a $p$-group has only one Sylow subgroup (itself), but is not necessarily abelian. Example: the quaternionic group $Q_8$.

Answer (score -1):

Well, like Bernard pointed out even the first direction is false but if you put nilpotent instead of abelian then it is true in both direction.

Comment: Can you also include the proof of your claim. That would make your answer more helpful to the OP and the others.

Comment: @JohnMa Is it not standard that $G$ is nilpotent iff $G$ is the product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Whether it is standard or not, the answer now is more like a comment than an answer. I would suggest either the answer add more context, or this answer should be deleted. @QuangHoang